# how to select item in angular 5?

Tags: angular

I have countries select which include first component definition:

```
public countries: Country[];
private selectedCountry: Country;
```

I have a select in html:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="company.country" (change)="onSelectCountry($event)" style="width: 120px">
        <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c">{{c.country.name}}</option>
      </select>
```

And the change method:

```
onSelectCountry(val)  {
    this.selectedCountry = val.target.value;
    alert(this.selectedCountry.name);
  }
```

I'm getting 'undefined' and if I omit the '.name' I'm getting '0: Object' where the 0 is the index of the item in the array,
any idea how can I get from here the Country object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your value from c to c.country

```
<option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c.country">{{c.country.name}}</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of handling the `change` DOM event, you can handle `ngModelChange` which will pass the selected Country as the `$event` parameter:

```
<select ... (ngModelChange)="onSelectCountry($event)">
```

The event handler would be defined as:

```
onSelectCountry(country)  {
    this.selectedCountry = country;
    ...
}
```

Please note that, thanks to two-way data binding, `company.country` is also set to the selected Country. Handling `ngModelChange` can still be useful to do some additional processing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation here: https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor

Are you sure that you need to use $event.target.value inside the function? Doesn't it pass the value by default and not the whole event object?

I would think you just need the following:

```
onSelectCountry(val)  {
   this.selectedCountry = val;
   alert(this.selectedCountry);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in html component

```
<select class="form-control" name="filterColumn" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select ...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let column of columns" [value]="column.propertyName">
        {{ column.title }}
    </option>
</select>
```

If you want to access element select or change selected items use this code

```
onChange(value){
      //alert(JSON.stringify(value));
      console.log(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<select #ctrl="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry">
    <option *ngFor="let c of countries" value="c.country.name">{{c.country.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Your selectedCountry variable should get automatically updated like this, and you don't even need your onChange event to update it anymore. You can still use your onChange event for the alert or whatever else you'd like.